# how to solve issue unencrypted login request

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to solve issue unencrypted login request

Thanks

Comment: You should definitely add more information to your question in order to get an answer

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Your question is currently too vague to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTTPS to encrypt sensitive information sent from the client to the server such as username/password during login.